# ERPNext with K3s Helm Chart using Portainer

Tags: kubernetes, k3s, portainer, erpnext

I've been trying to deploy ERPNext via helm chart using Portainer. having issues with the worker pods and "create-site" pods. does anyone have any experience with ERPNext and their helm chart?

I want to use a pre-made pvc named erp-pvc with ingress-nginx, and metallb. but no joy.
here's the link to the helm chart on my git.

https://github.com/limskey/helm-charts/blob/main/erp-next-helm-chart.yaml

any help is appreciated.

deployment of services/pods.

Comment: Thank you for your question. Questions focused specifically on Kubernetes, such as configuring or deploying a cluster, may be better answered by the experts in either the [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/). These platforms are highly knowledgeable in Kubernetes and can provide comprehensive support tailored to your needs. As a reminder, all questions on Stack Overflow must be specifically related to programming. We appreciate your understanding and encourage you to visit the "on-topic" pages of either site before posting there to ensure a more relevant and helpful response.